# How to select visible pixels for all layers in layer group in PS CC?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am wondering if there is an easy way of selecting the visible pixels from a layer group (with some sub-groups).  I know I can select them individually or turn them into a smart object, but I want it to be quick and retain the editability of separate layers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the move tool.(shortcut V) and then

1. You can either select the layer by pressing CTRL and clicking that particular layer.
2. You can check the auto select option available at the top menu. (tools option menu)
   [image]

Comment: I edited your question to remove the information that was unrelated. Self-promotion is not forbidden, but it has to be justified. In this case, it wasn't.

Comment: Doh! I had been doing this, but was expecting to see the marching ants so never tried pasting what I'd copied!  Was effectively just trying to 'trim' the whitespace for pasting partial content into new file.  Thanks.

Comment: This is not working, [it's only selecting the pixels from layers which have more than 50% opacity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYScT.png)!