# Photoshop: Ctrl + click on group no longer selecting all pixels on layers beneath?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Back in the 2018 version of Photoshop CC, you could control/command + left click on a a group to select all visible pixels, but it appears that is no longer working anymore for 2021 (I skipped a few). Is there any way to re-enable this ability or is it gone for good?

For the record: [This doesn't address the issue.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/45979/how-to-select-visible-pixels-for-all-layers-in-layer-group-in-ps-cc)

To reiterate, it used to be where you could control + click the group to select all pixels of the layers inside. Has this been changed to something I'm unaware of, or is it gone?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE I've still got CC2018, and AFAIK it doesn't work there either.

Comment: @Scott Another way is to Ctrl+Shift+click each layer you want to add to a selection, doesn't work on groups though. Like you,  I don't think it ever has.

Comment: Select group, Duplicate `Cmd+J`, Merge `Cmd+E`, then select pixels just like you would normally and finally delete the duplicated/merged layer if needed.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe <kbd>Command/Crl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> has *ever* worked for *Groups*. I believe you are mis-remembering. It works for layers or smart objects, but never "groups".

There **is** a somewhat hidden shortcut though which *can* load the alpha as a selection. This *may* get around the fact that there's no direct "click" method.

With **only** the group *visible*, you can hold the <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> keys and hit the <kbd>2</kbd> key. This will load *visibly transparent areas* as a selection.

This shortcut is essentially a **Channels Panel** shortcut. So it "sees" what channels see. Just turn off visibility for everything *except* your Group. To do that merely hold the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key down and click the **Visibility icon** next to the group in the **Layers Panel**.

So, to sum it up...

- Hold <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> and click the **Visibility icon** next to the Group in the **Layers Panel**
- Hold <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> and hit <kbd>2</kbd>
- Hold <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> and click the **Visibility icon** next to the Group in the **Layers Panel** again

  <sub>- Hides all other layers

    - Selects alpha based upon what is visible

    - Shows all layers again</sub>

You can also click the Selection icon at the bottom of the **Channels Panel** rather than using the `Command/Ctrl-Option/Alt-2` shortcut. Or.. just hold <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> and click the CMYK/RGB Channel thumbnail on the **Channels Panel** -- that will also load transparency as a selection.

## White Pixels...

I should also point out that **white can be problematic**. Because this is a **Channels** shortcut, and on *channels* white is equivalent to transparency, all white will be seen as transparent and therefore **not** part of any selection. **White will *not* be seen.** If you have white pixels in the artwork, you may need to combine selection methods to get all visible pixels, including white, to be part of (or absent from) any selection.

Comment: Alt+4 selects Blue channel so Ctrl+Alt+4 will load transparency for blue channel you want Ctrl+Alt+2 to load transparency from RGB channel.

Comment: Thanks @LilBro -- must've been a typing slip.. corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an action that does the following:

- duplicate current group
- merge duplicated group
- control click the layer created by merging the group (the selection is created)
- delete the layer created

I've mapped this to ctrl+F8, all I have to do is highlight the group and press "ctrl+F8"